# What could be the reasons that prevents an email being sent from a flow action?

Tags: visual-workflow, lightning-experience

I've been working on a flow that sends an email and a custom notification when meets certain criteria, everything is working well and as expected, after the deploy the team that requested this feature started to report that they're not getting the emails, even they did in the tests.

I've already tried to get the email logs but these emails don't appear there, I check the Deliverability option, it's All Email right now.

For now I'm waiting a message from someone before triggering this flow and set an debug log for their user.

As the title says, are there any other configurations that I could have missed?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](/tour). Including a [Minimal, Complete and Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful. Flow debug log would be a good place to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using the Send Email action and not an Email Alert here. In the past when I run into this same issue, it's usually one of the following:

- Deliverability issues in the target org (I know you said you already checked that, but for anyone else seeing this later on).
- Missing required fields for the Send Email action. I think that should throw an error, but I've had the flow continue without them if I recall.
- Null variables for email values. Similar to above. If using variables to populate the to, from, body, etc for the email, double and triple check that they have values before the email is sent
- Incorrect Sender Type configuration. I think once I set the from address to an Org Wide Email Address, but did not specify OrgWideEmailAddress as sender type, so it wouldn't send.
- No user access to Org Wide Email Address. If you set the OWEA to User Selection, but the intended users don't have access to it, that may be a cause.
- If the flow is launched by Guest users on an experience cloud site, a recent change by SF in a release made it so that emails generated by a guest user can ONLY be sent from a verified OWEA. So if the Send Email action is not configured to do that properly, the emails won't send

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Miguel, thank you, for some reason the emails are being sent with no issues, I'm just assuming it's SF being SF, hopefully I'll use your options in the future, as well if anyone ends here. TYSM